# Problems with implementing and running Here API

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, sdk, here-api

I'm trying to build an app with the [Here Maps API](https://developer.here.com/).

Based on this [example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/dev_guide/topics/app-create-simple.html) , I try to build the very basic form of a Here map in my app.

By following the instructions I still had to manage a load of issues. I managed most of them I think but there are some problems with or in the Java compiler (I guess?). It tells me that a deprecated API has to be overwritten.

When I use the "Make Project" function, Android Studio gives me 4 errors after checking the Java compiler:

> - Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
>     merging dex archives
> - Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives
> - Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
> - Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.a.a.a$a

Is there something with the example from Here Developers that is outdated right now and has to be fixed manually? I just used the instructions in that example, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if your gradle file dependencies are looking something like this. Include HERE-sdk.aar explicitly like given below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['HERE-sdk.aar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Android Studio do you use? Do you use additional dependencies in your app?

Seems there are mismatches in dex archives. To solve that, could you pease try to update app/build.gradle with the following?

```
    android {
        defaultConfig {
           multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
```